# How to override order api in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, orders, rest-api

I want to get order detail with customized some information using order API. I want to override API:

https://example.com/index.phprest/V1/orders

How can I override in Magento 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add an after plugin to the order repository in the webapi_rest area. Follow the next steps

1. Create the file `Vendor/Module/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository">
        <plugin name="order_repository" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository" disabled="false" sortOrder="200" />
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Add the plugin `Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Sales/Model/OrderRepository.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository as ModelOrderRepository;

class OrderRepository
{

    /**
     * @param ModelOrderRepository $orderRepository
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(
        ModelOrderRepository $orderRepository,
        OrderInterface $order
    ) {

        // Change the value for the order here
        return $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: will it work only for order API?

Comment: Yes, only for order API

Comment: thanks, it is working & now I am able to change order data.

Comment: How we can item base price using it ?