# Magento 2 how to modify SKU in order rest api response

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, sales-order, rest-api

I have to edit the SKU with some other data. When I use this rest API below

```
http://localhost.com/rest/V1/orders/1
```

I get SKU in two places like below.
Place one at the first like below

```
"items": [
        {
        
            "sku": "Test1-20,
            "store_id": 9,
            "tax_amount": 795.94,
            "tax_invoiced": 795.94,
            "tax_percent": 9.375,
            "updated_at": "2021-11-17 19:45:18",
            "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
            "weight": 610,
            "product_option": {
                "extension_attributes": {
                    "custom_options": [
                        {
                            "option_id": "1919",
                            "option_value": "13817"
                        },
                        
                    ]
                }
            },
 ]
```

And inside extension attributes like below.

```
"extension_attributes": {
    "shipping_assignments": [
        {
            "shipping": {
                "address": {
                    "address_type": "shipping",
                    "city": "ttes",
                    "country_id": "US",
                    "email": "test@gmail.com",
                    "entity_id": 111,
                    "firstname": "123",
                    "lastname": "111",
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "postcode": "636006",
                    "region": "TN",
                    "region_code": "TN",
                    "region_id": 1,
                    "street": [
                        "Fort street"
                    ],
                    "telephone": "123123"
                },
                "method": "free-ship",
            "items": [
                {
                    "sku": "Test1-20",
                    "store_id": 9,
                    "tax_amount": 795.94,
                    "tax_invoiced": 795.94,
                    "tax_percent": 9.375,
                    "updated_at": "2021-11-17 19:45:18",
                    "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
                    "weight": 610,
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Need to change SKU in the both places but couldn't find one exact professional way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way should be to create plugins for OrderRepository and OrderItemRepository, in detail:

- create plugin OrderRepository:afterGet() method
- create plugin OrderItemRepository:afterGetList() method

This will give you control over OrderInterface and OrderItemInterface, and so manipulating the sku as you like.

Here you find an answer about creating OrderRepository plugins
[How to override order api in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319219/how-to-override-order-api-in-magento-2)